# debugging issue with iphone simulator 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4

Friends,

I am building and debugging my xproj. Now the control is not stopping at the breakpoint i kept in the program but it is stopping at the return statement of operator++() in the stl_iterator.h file. After I press Continue the code is giving expected results but the thing is I cannot see the step by step debugging. Can any one give me clue why it is happening so, always i see the control at same position. I cleaned all targets and tried but no luck.

Active SDK = iphonesimulator4.0, Active Configuration = Build.  (I used C++ in the code).

With iphoneSImulator3.1.2, i can able to debug step-by-step for the same code.

Thanks in Advance,
Anil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the compiler will optimize your code and make breakpoints move around. Be sure to turn off all optimizations when building for debugging purposes; this should already be set in the “Debug” build setting.

Comment: Temporarily, my problem is solved but there is alot here for me to understand..  digging things out.  Anyway, Thanks Jeff Kelley, for your response